# Linq self-join and filter

Tags: c#, linq, self-join

I have a `List<ClaimEvent>` made up of this class:

```
public class ClaimEvent
{
    public ClaimEventType ClaimEventClaimEventType { get; set; }
    public DateTime OccurredOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

'ClaimEventType' is like so...

```
public class ClaimEventType
{
    public ClaimEventType()
    {
        Cancels = new List<ClaimEventType>();
        CancelledBy = new List<ClaimEventType>();
    }

    public int ClaimEventTypeId { get; set; }
    public string ClaimEventTypeName { get; set; }
    public List<ClaimEventType> Cancels { get; set; }
    public List<ClaimEventType> CancelledBy { get; set; }
}
```

`Cancels` lists all event types that this event cancels when it appears after them in the list ordered by `OccurredOn`. `CancelledBy` is the inverse, that is, the event is cancelled if one of the `CancelledBy` events appears after it.

How can I query a list of these objects so that items that are cancelled by other items in the list do not appear in the results?

Comment: This class contains neither `OccurredOn` or any other kind of date time. How would you be joining these together?

Comment: I was just adding that part, sorry. Should be clear now.

Comment: are the `Cancels` and `CancelledBy` lists already populated when you want to do your filtering?

Comment: @Anthony: yes they are. I omitted the code for brevity

Answer (score 2):

Pretty straightforward, though you seem to be duplicating effort listing both cancels and cancelled by:

```
List<ClaimEvent> theList = new List<ClaimEvent>();

theList.RemoveAll(i => (from j in theList
                        where j.ClaimEventClaimEventType.Cancels.Contains(i.ClaimEventClaimEventType) &&
                        j.OccurredOn > i.OccurredOn
                        select j).Count() > 0);
```

Remove all elements from the collection object where there exists another ClaimEvent in the collection that cancels a ClaimEvent of this element's type and occurred after this claim event (i.e. where there are one or more such elements).

**EDIT: Functionally equivalent code with more readable syntax**

This may also be accomplished using a second delegate method in a call to `Exists` to find any cancelling events:

```
theList.RemoveAll(i =>
    theList.Exists(j =>
        j.ClaimEventClaimEventType.Cancels.Contains(i.ClaimEventClaimEventType) &&
        j.OccurredOn > i.OccurredOn));
```

**Resources**

[MSDN: List(Of T).RemoveAll Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx)

Comment: I was trying all kinds of self-joins. I had no idea the RemoveAll method existed! Thanks! I provide both Cancels and CancelsBy to allow for different ways of thinking about events and how they cancel each other. It will make the data easier to model for business users designing workflows, but, yes, harder for me to program about.

Comment: Oh there are a TON of wonderful extension methods to use. I abuse `FindAll` very frequently to help me filter down a set of results, which technically could have been used here just as well by changing the conditional from a `Count() > 0` to `Count = 0`, but syntactically the `RemoveAll` speaks more to what you intend to do.

Comment: There's a bug in this. I don't want the cancellING events, I want the CancellED events. You should be selecting `i`, not `j`

Comment: You're not trying to select an `i` with this call, but rather flag it for removal. This predicate only returns a **Boolean** that says "True or false: One or more events exists (i.e. `Count() > 0`) that would cancel me and cause me to be removed from the list." I'm going to edit the answer with a link to more information on the extension and using predicates in general.

Comment: I've added in an equivalent code edit that may make more sense if what's happening in the first isn't entirely apparent. I think I like the edited code better anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, I think you might want to go for something like this. It essentially iterates over the sequence and builds a `HashSet` of event types already present. For each `ClaimEvent` in the sequence, it checks the previously existing event types for one of the current object's cancelling types. If it doesn't find one, it can yield the current object and add its type to the set.

```
public static IEnumerable<ClaimEvent> GetUncancelledEvents(this IEnumerable<ClaimEvent> source)
{   
    // note: override Equals & GetHashCode in ClaimEventType**
    HashSet<ClaimEventType> existingEventTypes = new HashSet<ClaimEventType>();

    foreach (var @event in source)
    {
        bool isCancelled = false;
        foreach (var cancellingEvent in @event.ClaimEventClaimEventType.CancelledBy)
        {
            if (existingEventTypes.Contains(cancellingEvent))
            {
                isCancelled = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!isCancelled)
        {
            existingEventTypes.Add(@event.ClaimEventClaimEventType);
            yield return @event;
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
var uncancelledEvents = eventsList.GetUncancelledEvents();
```